# How to use scp -i without prompting the key

Tags: scp

I use the following line in a gitlab pipeline :

```
scp -i "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" -r dist  user@1.1.1.1:/home/user/preprod
```

However when this line is executed the private key is prompted in the pipeline console, which is obviously a security issue.

The server is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What's the content of `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`? Is it a filename as it is supposed to be?

Comment: It is a Gitlab variable (https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#variables)
You think putting the variable in a file before using scp -i would solve my issue ?

Comment: No, I meant `scp -i` expects the name of the file that contains the private key, e.g. `/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa` and I was asking whether your `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` contains something similar.

Comment: From your comments on the answers I got the impression that the variable actually contains the _key_ (like `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEsexz4...`). That's wrong. It should contain the _name of the file_ that contains the key, not the key itself.

Comment: Well doing `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null` before the `scp -i` line allow me to use `scp` without the `-i` option

Answer (score 1):

There a two ways to avoid the password prompts:

1. Use SSH keys without password (hit enter when prompted for a password from `ssh-keygen`
2. Use `ssh-agent` as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/)

Comment: I do have a ssh key without password, the copy part is working fine, but then the content of the private key is printed to the console

Answer (score 1):

scp uses ssh wrapper and invoking the "-i" option requires the private key. You need to install the public key on your remote server.

Comment: I have the public key on my server, the file are correctly copied but the content of the key is printed in the gitlab pipeline console